# want to show a time for the comment last posted through php

Tags: php

I want to show when the comment last posted in PHP. like 5 minutes ago, 2 days ago, 7 weeks ago. How to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what content management system you are using?  Or if it is homebrewed, can you post the php that allows comments on your site?

Comment: Generally this would be done in Javascript, as then you can use server-side caching. However, I can't seem to find the link.

Comment: In what format is the time/date that you want to convert?

Comment: Is this question about how to generate fuzzy time, or how to print it?

Comment: I want to compare the updated_date which I get through a comments table and in PHP code I want to compare this updated_date (2010-01-15 16:46:43) with the current date time and show how many time before the comment posted.

Like on stack overflow you get about how many time before the question is posted (3 mins ago).

Answer (score 1):

You can find plenty of answers with full solutions in different languages, pseudocode, ideas, etc.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time).

I believe there's an example of PHP too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeago, a jQuery plugin, to do it via Javascript. It would yield the same result, update without refreshing, and by doing it client side instead of server side, you are not precluded from caching.

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Otherwise, Annurag has a link with some good PHP solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do manual calculation in server, to get the time difference, then translate it into human time format.

Or my preference, do it in browser using javascript. Using this approach, the time in page can be updated without refresing the page.

You can use this [jQuery EasyDate library](http://easydate.parshap.com/) to translate a DOM element into humane time format.

You can also read the comments in this post about [Pretty Date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) by John Resig. It contain the code, and improvement by other.

Answer (score 0):

Store the comment posted in the date DB and show the the same in the front end by comparing with current date and time using php function